# Como Comparar un String con otro para ver si dentro del primer String se encuentra el segundo?

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio en el que tengo que crear un programa para descifrar un código oculto en un mensaje, hasta ahora lo he hecho tal que así, introduzco el mensaje, introduzco la palabra a buscar, descompongo la palabra en letras y mira si están en el mensaje, el problema que me bloquea  es que al comprobar si las letras están en el mensaje, si una letra esta repetida, me muestra siempre la primera ocurrencia, de modo que en las pruebas me dan resultados falsos ya que puede contener las letras pero no en el orden indicado ni en su totalidad, claro que en el código no le indico lo contrario, pero es ahí donde tengo el bloqueo y por el cual no avanzo.

Lo que quiero conseguir es saber si en el titular está escondida la palabra a buscar, encontrando las letras, tal y como aparecen en el orden  la palabra a buscar.

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    //introduzco numero de casos de prueba
    System.out.println("Casos a analizae");
    int casosPrueba = s.nextInt();

    System.out.println("##########");
    //creo un contador
    int count = 0;
    do {
        System.out.println("caso " + (count + 1));

        //introduzco el titular en el que buscar
        System.out.println("*************");
        System.out.println("titular");
        String titular = s.nextLine();
        titular = titular.replace(" ", "");//quito los espacios dejando la frase toda junta
        titular = titular.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);//paso la entrada a minuscula y evito caracteres que no sean abcd inglés


        //introduzco lo que quiero buscar
        System.out.println("************");
        System.out.println("busqueda");
        String looknMsg = s.nextLine();
        looknMsg = looknMsg.replace(" ", "");
        looknMsg = looknMsg.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);


        System.out.println("*********f***********");

        //recorro la 'palabra a buscar' para deconstruirla en letras
        for (int j = 0; j < looknMsg.length(); j++) {
            char letra = looknMsg.charAt(j);

            //creo un indice de la letra
            int idx = titular.indexOf(letra);
            //int idx2=titular.lastIndexOf(letra);

            //letra ? esta en la frase : no esta
            if (idx != -1) {
                System.out.println(letra + " esta en la frase en la posicion " + idx);                   
            } else {
                System.out.println(" no esta");
            }
        }

        //auemento el contador en cada iteracion para finalizar programa
        count++;

    } while (count < casosPrueba);
```

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la salida que me saca, pero como se ve las letras, solo me muestra la primera ocurrencia que encuentra, cuando yo lo que espero que me muestre es las letras en la posición en la que se encuentra cada una de ellas.

por ejemplo:

titular:

> mateo tiene una amapola blanca para regalo

busqueda:

> tia amparo

```
t pos 2
i pos 6
a pos 12
a pos 13
m pos 16
p pos 18
a pos 21
r pos 28
o pos 33
```

Comment: Saludos, seria bueno si podrias poner un ejemplo, el ingreso de datos para tus pruebas y la salida que esperas ;)

Comment: El problema es que no indicas lo que quieres conseguir. Sí, tu programa tal cual está busca la primera ocurrencia en la cadena, pero no queda claro en tu pregunta qué es lo que quieres. Si quieres ver si hay más coincidencias, haz un sustring de la cadena empezando en la posición que te ha retornado el indexOf previo, hasta que termines la cadena y no encuentre ninguna ocurrencia más. Pero lo dicho, sin una pregunta clara, no tendrás respuestas concisas.

Comment: @Israel-ICM , he editado la pregunta y a ver si asi me explico un poco mejor, disculpad el no explicarme bien

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bueno quise continuar con el metodo que ya tenias armado pero se me hizo un poco raro jejeje, asi que me parecio mas rapido armar uno nuevo, está comentado para que comprendas lo que realice:

```
String texto = "mateo tiene una amapola blanca para regalo";
String buscar = "tia amparo";

texto = texto.replaceAll(" ", "").toLowerCase();
buscar = buscar.replaceAll(" ", "").toLowerCase();
int indexUltimoCaracter = 0; // Variable auxiliar para guardar el ultimo indice
for (int i = 0; i < buscar.length(); i++) { // Iteramos en base al texto a buscar
    for (int j = indexUltimoCaracter; j < texto.length(); j++) { // Iteramos el texto a partir del ultimo indice encontrado
        if (buscar.charAt(i) == texto.charAt(j)) {
            System.out.println(buscar.charAt(i) + " => " + j);
            indexUltimoCaracter = j + 1; // Aqui asignamos el ultimo indice encontrado (Sumamos 1 para que comience desde el siguiente caracter)
            break; // Una vez encontrado el caracter rompemos el for para pasar al siguiente caracter
        }
    }
}
```

Salida que obtengo:

```
t => 2
i => 6
a => 12
a => 13
m => 14
p => 16
a => 19
r => 28
o => 35
```

Espero te sirva ;) Saludos